# How to show injectivity of a multivariable function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x+y\neq -1\}$.
Define $f:A\to \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
f(x,y)=\left(\frac{x}{1+x+y},\frac{y}{1+x+y}\right).
$$

Is this injective or not on $A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously injective, because the system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\xi  &= \frac{x}{1+x+y},\\
\eta &= \frac{y}{1+x+y},
\end{align}
\right.
$$
has a unique solution given by
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{\xi }{1-\eta-\xi},\\
y &= \frac{\eta }{1-\eta-\xi}
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Comment: @enzotibIf I use the formal method by taking two arbitrary points  $(x,y)$  and $(a,b)$ such that $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$ then eventually I reached at $x+y=a+b$, now from this can we say that $(x,y)=(a,b)$? as the points are taken arbitrarily

Comment: The system has a unique solution means that you cannot have two different points $(x,y)$ and $(a,b)$ such that $f(x,y)=f(a,b)$.

Comment: I got your point but my intention is to show the points are same